# PostgreSQL Select statement produces errors in datagrip but not pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, datagrip

I can run the following script without errors in pgadmin4

```
SELECT * from tbl
```

I have tried the following in datagrip

```
SELECT * from tbl
```

and

```
SELECT * from public.tbl
```

Neither of the above scripts worked. The following error was returned:

```
[2018-05-12 21:16:44] [42P01] ERROR: relation "public.tbl" does not exist
[2018-05-12 21:16:44] Position: 15
```

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being really simple and a very silly mistake, but hopefully this will help someone else.

I simply needed to select the correct database. The default is `postgres`. The database I had my tables in was `webadmin`. You can change the database when you make your connection in datagrip. The screen where I made the change looked like this

[image]

Answer (score -1):

@Alex,

It's better to change a search path at top right angle of the console
[image: search path selection]

Refer to [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/schemas.html)

Comment: Pictures are worth a thousand words but an answer as a script showing how to change schemas is easier to search for by Google.